Does strengthening the antecedent hold in Aristotelian logic and its extensions?
Does strengthening the antecedent hold in Aristotelian logic and its extensions? I ask because of the following:
GUIDE

Let A signify all
Let E signify no
Let I signify some
Let O signify not all
Let addition signify disjunction
Let multiplication signify conjunction
Let N signify negation
Let R signify some relation
Let “→” signify logical consequence, not the material conditional.

PROBLEM

Let a signify dogs
Let b signify fish
Let c signify mammals
Let R signify are
AaRc→A(ab)Rc
(5) translates to all dogs are mammals. Thus, all dogs and fish are mammals. The conclusion seems true. Otherwise, if the conclusion is false, then the negation is true. The negation of all dogs and fish are mammal are some dogs and fish are not mammal, which is false.


Classical logic permitted strengthening the antecedent generally does not hold in Aristotelian logic without additional assumptions where statements about one category such as dogs cannot automatically extend to conjunction of two categories such as dogs and fish here, unless implied by additional premises such as "All fish are mammals" here. This negation being false does not imply the original argument is valid. It only shows that A(ab)Rc cannot be false if AaRc and additional assumptions hold true...

Your 5 seems to me to mean: all dogs are mammals, therefore all things that are both dogs and fish are mammals. Depending on how you interpret Aristotle's logic that might be true, or it might be inapplicable, since nothing is both a dog and a fish.

Naw, naw, you're trying to get away with something, and you didn't even hide it good. It reminds me of watching the homeless gentlemen throwing three-card Monte behind the liquor store.
You created an unnecessary encoding to hide an invalid inference. Translating AaRc→A(ab)Rc into ordinary language is:  ∀dog IsMammal(dog) → ismammal(dog, fish). That's assuming the lack of a space after the ")" indicates the logical product.
You provided absolutely no justification for that inference. You only just obfuscated it using a secret code ring.
You wouldn't even get away with that behind the liquor store!
